# How to "close" or "destroy" a specific counter in Opentelemetry?

Tags: java, counter, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm trying to close or destroy the specific counter which is exported to Prometheus.

For eg:-
If we have two counters and exporting the counter values in the prometheus but i need to destroy one of the counter instead of shut downing the whole SDK ( openTelemetrySdk.shutdown()).
Can we stop the reporting of specific metrics, including counters.

```
     Meter sampleMeter = openTelemetry.getMeter("io.opentelemetry.example.metrics");
      LongCounter counter = sampleMeter.counterBuilder("example.counter.sampleMeter").build();
      LongUpDownCounter counter2 = sampleMeter.upDownCounterBuilder("example.second.counter.sampleMeter").build();
      counter.add(1);
      counter2.add(1);
```

Is there any ways to use the metrics registry in Opentelemetry like how we use it in the dropwizard-metrics?
So that i can register or deregister the metrics and keep only the required metrics data.
https://www.baeldung.com/dropwizard-metrics#2-metricregistry

Comment: As mentioned by Gregor, it is possible to close async instruments. However, its not currently possible for synchronous instruments. See this issue for more details: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/issues/2232

Answer (score 0):

Each OpenTelemetry metric (except histogram) has an async variant, which has a `close()` method that stops the metric.

Here's an example:

```java
meter.counterBuilder(METRIC_NAME_UNLOADED)
     .setDescription(METRIC_DESCRIPTION_UNLOADED)
     .setUnit(Constants.UNIT_CLASSES)
     .buildWithCallback(measurement -> measurement.record(unloaded))
```